# Use Vertical Mapper Grid file in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, vertical-mapper

I have coverage plot in Vertical Mapper grid format and I want to create a store using it in GeoServer.

QGIS can read the grid file and shows a nice plot. My grid file has 4 bands, possibly RGB and data. [image: Attached is the way it looks in QGis]

I converted the grid file to ASCII Grid using gdal_translate using band 4. Now data could be loaded into GeoServer but it is not showing anything.

Is there any extension for GeoServer which can help me load this data in GeoServer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert it to GeoTIFF using some utility first (e.g.,  gdal_translate, FME), GeoServer cannot read that format natively.

Comment: Is there an extension which can make GeoServer read it. Because QGis can read the grd file.

Comment: Also tell me the best command to convert to geotiff.